# Python MySQLdb string substitution without added quotations

Tags: python, mysql

I'd like to use string substitution for a comma-separated list, such as:

```
query = """SELECT id, name, image_id
           FROM users
           WHERE id IN (%s)
           """
values = (','.join(uids))
results = dbc.getAll(query, values
```

This executes the query:

```
SELECT id, name, image_id
FROM users
WHERE id IN ('1,2,3')
```

Which does not work as expected.

How can I do a substution so that I get the query without the quotations, such as:

```
SELECT id, name, image_id
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let MySQLdb do the entire argument substitution. In this case, the expected argument, `values`, should be the sequence `(1,2,3)`, rather than the string `'1,2,3'`:

```
query = """SELECT id, name, image_id
           FROM users
           WHERE id IN %s
           """    
values = uids
results = dbc.getAll(query, [values])
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked this way:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (pids_list,))
```

and I made sure that elements of the pids_list are **integers** and not strings.