# Python parameter formatting value in MySQL string

Tags: python, string, formatting

In Python I'm passing in two variables to MySQL, and the second variable is referenced as `{0}` and works correctly.

How can I make the first parameter do the same thing ? If '{0}' is the second variable. What is the First ? `dbname` is incorrect, I need to show `dbname`'s value in this string ?

```
def checkTableExists(dbname,tablename):
    sql2 = """SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = " dbname "
        AND table_name = '{0}' """.format(tablename.replace('\'', '\'\''))
```

Comment: You should not do parameter substitution this way. You need to do it the safe way see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936957/python-mysqldb-string-substitution-without-added-quotations

Comment: This does not do what you think. `{0}` refers to **the first parameter passed to .format()**. In your case it is `tablename.replace('\'', '\'\'')`. Also use a proper escaping code (I'm sure whatever library you use it does support it).

Answer (score 0):

A better way to organize your function to create the query might be:

```
def checkTableExists(dbname, tablename):
    query_args = {"table_name":tablename, "database_name":dbname}
    exist_query = """
        SELECT EXISTS (
            SELECT * 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = '%(table_name)s' 
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '%(database_name)s') AS `Exist`
        """%(query_args)

    # Do stuff with the `Exist` column of whatever your db connection returns.
    # Should be 1 if True. Might be good to just return bool(...).
```

This is what `EXISTS` is for, so you don't need to do a "hack" and check yourself if the `COUNT` within `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` is greater than 0.

As @jgranger commented on the OP, if you are using MySQLdb, you can follow that link and let it do the argument substitution. But there are many other flavors of interaction with pyodbc, so string-formatted queries will never go away (I wish they would).

**Even Better**

Write a stored procedure in SQL that checks if tables exist as a function of the database name and schema name, and then do nothing but pass arguments to this stored procedure. Then any component of the system (Python or otherwise) can expect that stored procedure's interface for existence checking.

If the existence-check logic needs to change (say in your application it suddenly matters that a table has more than 0 rows rather than merely having been created with a `CREATE TABLE` command, or vice versa), then you can change the internals of the stored procedure without needing to go to every downstream location that had embedded string SQL queries and change the logic. It helps add modularity and encapsulation to the system's interaction with the databases.